# Installing Windows (10?) for dual boot on Ubuntu PC

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-10

I have a PC running Ubuntu 14.04, and I wanted to install Windows as well, for gaming purposes. I've read that it's safer to install Windows first, but it's too late for that, so I wanted to partition my drive to add Windows 10. How can I do this safely? If there isn't a way to do so, should I use two hard drives instead?

Comment: Will partitioning effect performance at all? My drive is 7200 rpm 1 TB

Comment: No not really.  Just probably got to defrag your Windows partition.